# Cannot create new text files by C++ in Codeblocks in Mac

Tags: c++, macos, text-files, codeblocks

I have a C++ code in Codeblocks in Mac OS that should create some .txt files and write something on them. It worked on Windows, however, it does not run correctly on Mac. It does not make any errors, and it announces that the procedure is terminated with status 0; however, it does not create any .txt files!! What can be the problem?
It even does not claim that Codeblocks needs special permission. Moreover, the execution window background is White; different from the usual execution window of Codeblocks, which is Black.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main(){ 
    for (int i=1;i<=1;i++){
        ofstream fout ("test1.txt");
        int n=rand()%10+1;
     //   int n=15;
        fout<<n<<endl;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

This code just does not create any .txt file in Mac, while it worked on Windows.

Comment: _I have a C++ code_ I don't see any code in your question, please add it, see [tour], [ask] and [mre].

Comment: this is typically an indication of Undefined Behavior, SO cannot help diagnose without seeing the code.

Comment: @JaMiT Hello. I did the changes. Still the same behavior.

Comment: Better. I would drop the looping aspect as well, especially since `for (int i=1;i<=1;i++)` will only iterate once anyway. (Sorry, I don't have an answer for this, just suggestions to make the question more attractive.)

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? Why do you expect it created at that specific place? Why aren't you checking for errors in the C++ code? Start doing it now, before ignoring errors has developed into a bad habit. By the way Codeblocks is a text editor. It is about as relevant as the colour of your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

"test1.txt"，this is a relative path, you maybe hava use clion,you must know where relative path, but it is using a absolute path.

Comment: This may be better as a comment to help the questioner answer the question, if it works you should post it as an answer after.